# Change web-page color based on user's input from previous page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, background-color

I have a form made in the previous page. In the form, I have a checklist with the options: red, green, blue.

If the user selects red, the next page's background color should be red. If green is selected, then the background color will be green. I am using PHP to do this.

Previous page

```
<form action="next_page.php method="POST>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="red">
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="green">
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="blue">
</form>
```

Next Page

```
<?PHP 
   $radioVal = $_POST["color"]
 ?>

 <style>
   .body{
     //what goes here
  }
 </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?PHP 
$radioVal = $_POST["color"];

echo "
 <style>
   .body{
     background-color:" . htmlspecialchars($radioVal) . "
  }
 </style>";
 ?>
```

Comment: You might add htmlspecialchars or another sanitizer. Also it's good to make if-else statement only for these color values.Your example works, but it's very easy for XSS Injection.

Comment: @Kristiyan  Thanks for the tip.  I added the htmlspecialchars to make it more safe for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

In no particular order:

- Use AJAX to get the data you need from the server.
- Echo the data into the page somewhere, and use JavaScript to get the
  information from the DOM.
- Echo the data directly to JavaScript.

Check out this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23740549/11336167)

Comment: Oh, by reading the link I understood: these are 3 different possibilities to achieve this! You should be more explicit on that. And by their question I think they already have a way to transfer the data, but no clue how to include it.